# HTML5 / CSS - Expand Horizontal Menu

Tags: html, css, menu

i spent about 1 day to resolve this problem, but i cannot reach any results.
i need to create a menu with some link that they are collapsed and when i hover on the parent `<li>` they appear next to it. Like a dropdown but in horizontal direction.

**EDIT:
*The "Uscite" and "Guide" links appear near "Blog", the others links
   need to slide right and come back when i move out the mouse ***

i tried to use the `display: none` and `display: block`, that seems to work but with this method i cannot apply any type of transition, so the result is a little bit ugly.
I tried also with google, but every thread found doesn't help me.

Can anyone help me? 
In this link you cand find my code: [Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/Alfaver/pen/Jmgpxz)

```css
.mpx_nav {
    background-color: rgba(98, 98, 98, 1);
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
}
.nav_menu a{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    color: #eee;
    line-height: 40px;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
.nav_menu a:hover {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #333;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
/*    background-color: rgba(98, 98, 98, 1);*/
    background-color: #eee;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 5;
}
.dropdown-content a {
    color: rgb(98, 98, 98);
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: rgb(98, 98, 98);
    color: #eee;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="mpx_nav">
   <ul class="nav_menu container">
    <a href="index.html"><li class="menu_item">Home</li></a>
    <a href="portfolio.html"><li class="menu_item">Portfolio</li></a>
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#"><li class="menu_item dropdown">Blog</li></a>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="#">Uscite</a>
                        <a href="#">Guide</a>
                    </div>
                </div>   
    <a href="#"><li class="menu_item">Su di Me</li></a>
    <a href="contact.html"><li class="menu_item">Contatti</li></a>
   </ul>
  </div>
```

Thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `white-space:nowrap` to make all links in one line. have a look at below snippet.

```css
.mpx_nav {
    background-color: rgba(98, 98, 98, 1);
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
}
.nav_menu li{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align : top
}
.nav_menu a{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    color: #eee;
    line-height: 40px;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    vertical-align : top
}
.nav_menu a:hover {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #333;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.dropdown {
    /*position: relative;*/
    /*display: inline-block;*/
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.dropdown-content {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align : top
    /*position: absolute;*/
/*    background-color: rgba(98, 98, 98, 1);*/
    /*background-color: #eee;*/
    /*min-width: 160px;*/
    /*box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);*/
    z-index: 5;
    width:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
.dropdown-content a {
    /*color: rgb(98, 98, 98);*/
    /*padding: 12px 16px;*/
    text-decoration: none;
    
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: rgb(98, 98, 98);
    color: #eee;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    /*display: inline-block;*/
    width:100%
}
```

```html
<div class="mpx_nav">
   <ul class="nav_menu container">
        <li class="menu_item"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li class="menu_item"><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li class=" menu_item dropdown">
                    <a href="#">Blog</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="#">Uscite</a>
                        <a href="#">Guide</a>
                    </div>
                </li>  
        
    <li class="menu_item"><a href="#">Su di Me</a></li>
    <li class="menu_item"><a href="contact.html">Contatti</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply, but probably cause my bad english i didn't ask the question in right way. 
My goal is to have the "uscite | Guide" links near the "blog" '<li>', the others links in the menu slide to the right and when you move out the mouse the 2 links disappear and the others come back to the left.

Comment: @MikeAlFaverFavro I have changed my answer, see if it close to your requirement. your `HTML` markup was not valid so I have changed a little bit.

Comment: Thank you so much !! That is was i needed !!

Answer (score 0):

```css
.mpx_nav {
    background-color: rgba(98, 98, 98, 1);
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
}
.nav_menu a{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    color: #eee;
    line-height: 40px;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
.nav_menu a:hover {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #333;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
/*    background-color: rgba(98, 98, 98, 1);*/
    background-color: #eee;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 5;
    white-space:nowrap
}
.dropdown-content a {
    color: rgb(98, 98, 98);
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: rgb(98, 98, 98);
    color: #eee;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="mpx_nav">
   <ul class="nav_menu container">
    <a href="index.html"><li class="menu_item">Home</li></a>
    <a href="portfolio.html"><li class="menu_item">Portfolio</li></a>
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#"><li class="menu_item dropdown">Blog</li></a>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="#">blog one</a>
                        <a href="#">blog two</a>
                    </div>
                </div>   
    <a href="#"><li class="menu_item">Su di Me</li></a>
    <a href="contact.html"><li class="menu_item">Contatti</li></a>
   </ul>
  </div>
```

you need to add

```
white-space:nowrap
```

to your css to align content in one line
you can also use this code if you face any difficulty with it feel free to ask

Comment: Thank you too, but as i reply at the guys before, i ask the wrong question. Sorry for that ! I edit the main post.
If is not possible to achieve my request, i will use this solution.